# Haxepunk: using google play services

Tags: google-play-services, haxe, openfl, haxepunk

I'm using HaxePunk and feel satisfied about it, except one little thing.

How can I use achievements, in-game purchasements fro, google play? Is there any lib for OpenFL or HaxePunk?

I've found only a lib on github, but seems like it is only for Flixel (not HaxePunk) and supports only IOS: https://github.com/prestia/hxgk-flixel

If there is no lib actually, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are the openfl premium libs with support Gamecenter/Play and in-app purchasements
http://www.openfl.org/marketplace/premium/

Comment: It's worth mentioning the GameCenter library is open source now. https://github.com/openfl/gamecenter

Answer (score 1):

Check my library https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/linden-google-play. Now it supports Leaderboard, Achievements and CloudSave. Another my lib https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/linden-google-iap support in-app purchases for GooglePlay.